# Java lambda expression and switch statement cause eclipse to crash normal?

Tags: java, eclipse

I just can't figure out what is causing a stackoverflow problem in eclipse. Well actually I do know, but I don't know why. I've tried the below:

1. Restarted my computer - duh
2. Eclipse.exe -clean
3. Reinstalled a new eclipse
4. Tested the exact same code every time, each time the exact same code appears to crash eclipse. The code is a lambda expression. Which is all fine until I press the period key "." for code completion within a switch statement.

My code is:

```
albumList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
        .addListener((ObservableValue obs, AbstractAlbum oldAlbum, AbstractAlbum selectedAlbum) -> {
     switch (type){
         test. // It doesn't matter what variable I use, valid or not, after the dot, eclipse crashes       
     }
});
```

I can't find anything wrong with my code. I followed this tutorial here: http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-intro/ which also has a lambda expression. I attempted to add a switch to this code and again it crashed:

```
lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
    switch (type){
        test. // again it crashed after a dot
    }
});
```

Can someone please confirm whether they can replicate this? I'm using a fresh Eclipse: Luna for java developer 64x - the latest package. Here is the log from eclipse:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-11-28 22:19:08.889
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.StackOverflowError)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.UnresolvedReferenceNameFinder.visit(UnresolvedReferenceNameFinder.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.traverse(Block.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Initializer.traverse(Initializer.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1427)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedAllocationExpression.traverse(QualifiedAllocationExpression.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LambdaExpression.traverse(LambdaExpression.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.traverse(MessageSend.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedAllocationExpression.traverse(QualifiedAllocationExpression.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LambdaExpression.traverse(LambdaExpression.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.traverse(MessageSend.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedAllocationExpression.traverse(QualifiedAllocationExpression.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LambdaExpression.traverse(LambdaExpression.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.traverse(MessageSend.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedAllocationExpression.traverse(QualifiedAllocationExpression.java:603)
```

Comment: Well, you have probably found a bug in Eclipse. Open a bug report ;)

Comment: Well... I was hoping that it wasn't a bug. How can I code without switch statement :( ... short from changing IDE... until this problem is fixed, I may have to disable content assist :(

Comment: use `groupingBy` method from `Collectors` to create groups of objects that match each switch cause. Then for each group call your code.

Comment: I've never used Collectors before. Can you give an example of how you would use it to replace a switch statement?

Comment: Hmmm it's actually not just a switch statement. Even a simple if statement will cause the IDE to hang. I tried it on a different computer, but it is still the same problem. I've logged a bug report. Hopefully this gets looked at soon.

Comment: Two years and major releases later, this is still happening. Crazy that Eclipse still can't handle Lambda expressions!

Comment: It is still crashing... :(

Comment: @eclipse  Same issue i am facing when i am try to get getter method inside forEach - > switch it start to say "Not Responding"

Comment: Same problem with Eclipse 4.6.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Oxygen and Eclipse Neon and both still crash on a switch inside a lambda forEach. Did you file a bug?

Comment: @all Move to a professional IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe time heals all wounds?  :-)

I use `Eclipse Neon 3` and all content assist with Java 8 works fine....

Comment: I am using Eclipse Oxygen and Eclipse Neon and both crash on a switch inside a lambda forEach.